# Do tree stumps do anything if you don't cut them down?

Tags: stardew-valley

When you cut down trees, you can cut them down to the stump, and then you can cut the stump down too:

[image]

**If you don't cut these stumps down, do they do anything?** I'm trying to figure out if there's any reason why I should leave them alone.

Like, do they eventually grow into new trees or something?

Comment: You means specifically doing something active, right? I'm curious about that too! (Though in this game, I consider “passively taking up space” as significant. :)

Comment: If my updated answer is now sufficient, please feel free to mark it as accepted for possible future viewers.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After some testing, it does appear that non-fruit bearing trees do **NOT** re-grow from stumps.

This information is taken from the updated [Wiki](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Trees#Non-Fruit_Bearing) page:

> Non-Fruiting trees take 10 to 12 days to grow from being planted, as
>   long as the tiles in a two tile radius remain clear. They will grow at
>   a reduced rate if other objects occupy part of this area and will not
>   grow beyond a sapling if there is another tree directly adjacent. Once
>   fully grown, the surrounding area can be paved with no ill effects on
>   the tree, although doing so will prevent seeds from being dropped.
>   These trees **do not regrow from a stump**, a new seed must always be
>   planted.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps there is something wrong with the game version or savefile I'm using, but according to my tests, stumps have two notable properties for me:

1. They continue to drop seeds/cones/acorns like full-size trees.
2. **They do not grow back into trees.** I've backed up my savefile and essentially slept through two seasons (while clearing seeds and debris around the stumps) to verify this. I tried varying the spacing between stumps and the tree type with no effect.

This is with Stardew Valley from GoG, v1.05. I don't know if it makes any difference, but I cut the trees down with an iridium axe. <sup>(Maybe the iridium is radioactive and kills trees while simultaneously making them sprout seeds from the stumps?)</sup>

Comment: I noticed that stumps don't grow back for me either, which is why I unaccepted one of the other previous answers. Maybe it depends on which version of the game you have, or maybe it's a bug, I'm not sure.

Comment: I have updated my answer after testing.

Answer (score 4):

They don't do anything except taking space and growing back to a tree after 10 days.

Normally, new trees take a long time to spawn (small tree appears, then grows to a big tree) if you chop them down completely. Therefore if you are planning to farm wood, leave the stumps; if not then chop the stump too.

Comment: Now it seems that it's confirmed stumps don't regrow.

Comment: See https://twitter.com/ConcernedApe/status/711010819861970944, answer by the game developer Concerned Ape.

Comment: I feel like this a detail that was changed. Also I think that trees outside the farm actually grow back, but I might be mistaken.